# HELP:problem in android xml code at eclipse 3.7

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

in one of my android app,all xml file not give me attribute prompt ,for example android: ,if i write as android: ,the eclipse not give me prompt ,i donot know why,my xml in other pc eclipse is all right,and xml file of my eclipse other android app can give me attribute prompt,i restart pc and eclipse but no use,why? my eclipse is 3.7
edit: i reinstall eclipse not help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:id="@+id/add">
  <LinearLayout  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center" 
              android:id="@+id/liangdu"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
              android:layout_marginBottom="90dip" >   
    <ImageView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sv"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
```

```
    <LinearLayout   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_above="@id/liangdu"
                    android:id="@+id/bottom" 
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dip"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_xuanzhuan" >
       <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dip"
                        >

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="20dip"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                      android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                      android:id="@+id/tv"
                      android:gravity="right"
                      android:text="亮    度"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <SeekBar

                      android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv"
                      android:id="@+id/liangduSeekBar"
                      android:layout_width="210dip" 

                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:minHeight="6dip"
                      android:maxHeight="6dip"
                      android:paddingLeft="15px"
                      android:paddingRight="5px"
                      android:max="100"
                      android:progress="50"
                      android:thumbOffset="3px"
                      android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
                      android:thumb="@drawable/seekbarthumb"/>

       </RelativeLayout>
       <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dip"
                        >

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="20dip"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                      android:id="@+id/tv"
                      android:text="对比度"
                      android:gravity="right"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            <SeekBar

                      android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv"
                      android:id="@+id/duibiSeekBar"
                      android:layout_width="210dip" 

                      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                      android:minHeight="6dip"
                      android:maxHeight="6dip"
                      android:paddingLeft="15px"
                      android:paddingRight="5px"
                      android:max="100"
                      android:progress="50"
                      android:thumbOffset="3px"
                      android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
                      android:thumb="@drawable/seekbarthumb"/>

       </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @pengwang: Please post one of your XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press `STR`+`SPACE`, does the auto-complete dialog show up? If so, you might want to [reduce the delay to `0`](http://www.netalive.org/swsu/archives/2005/04/instant_autocom.html).

Otherwise, [restoring the Editors defaults](http://manuelselva.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/no-more-eclipse-auto-completion/) might also help.

If nothing else works, you can create a new Workspace and import your old projects.

Comment: i modify as  your link but not use help

Comment: this is not custom view,my xml is common xml

Comment: thank you ,i last do as:create a new Workspace and import your old projects.